# Unable to delete the uploaded image

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails, groovy

HTML/GSP

```
<li class="gallery-item">
<form>
.....
    <a data-portfolio-id="${portfolioInstance?.id}" data-id="${part.id}" class="btn-delete" href="javascript:void(0);">
</form>

</li>
```

JS

```
$('.btn-delete').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
    url: '/deletePart/'+ $(this).data('id'),
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {

            $(this).closest('.gallery-item').fadeOut().remove();
                            //remove() seems not to be working?
        },
        error: function( error ) {
            console.log( error );
        }
    });
});
```

Controller

```
    def deletePart() {
    log.debug params
    def id = params.id?:params.partId
    def part = PortfolioPart.get(id)
    // log.debug " >>>>>>" + part
    def portfolio = part.portfolio

  try {
        part.delete(flush: true)
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.deleted.message', args: [message(code: 'part.label', default: 'PortfolioPart'), id])
    } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.deleted.message', args: [message(code: 'portfolio.label', default: 'Portfolio'), id])
        redirect(action: "edit", id: portfolio.id)
    }

    withFormat {
        html {
            redirect(action: "edit", id: portfolio.id)
        }
        json {
            def out = [id:id]
            render out as JSON
        }
    }
}
```

Tried to remove the image with its id that was uploaded previously, but it keeps giving me 500 internal server error.

**GET http://localhost/deletePart/[220]500 (internal server error)**

Any help is appreciated!

**Update**
Ok managed to get the error go away, but only left is remove() that doesn't remove the gallery-item block?

Comment: Any stacktrace? Anyways, `deletePart` doesn't look like finished, and doesn't return any response

Comment: @IgorArtamonov my apologies the deletePart is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the error message it seams that the **id** is a `String` and ids in Grails DB are `Long` so you need to convert it before calling the `get` method of the `PortfolioPart` Domain class:

```
def part = PortfolioPart.get(Long.valueOf(id).longValue());
```

To check if it is a String you can do :

```
 log.info("Id class = " + id.getClass().getName() );
```

Comment: thanks @daguru for the help but it doesn't resolve the error. The code is changed already but still facing same issue with different stacktrace error.

Comment: different stacktrace error means different error :) can you show us the error ?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an issue where Domain objects by default have a method to parse the params id to a long, where your object does not have this method. Params are a collection of strings so what you need to do is change your param.id from a string to a long. Try:

```
def part = PortfolioPart.get(params.long('id'))
```

Good luck.

Comment: you mean i need to convert from string to long in controller?

Comment: I believe that should hopefully fix the problem

Comment: unfortunately it does not :( but thanks for your help

Comment: yes still got same error till the code is changed. Still facing same issue with different stacktrace error.